# Django Rest Framework Conditional Field on Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that references a [Generic Relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) that I want to serialize in a detailed manner.

```
class AType(models.Model):
    foo = CharField()


class BType(models.Model):
    bar = PositiveIntegerField()


class ToSerialize(models.Model):
    scope_limit = models.Q(app_label="app", model="atype") | \
                  models.Q(app_label="app", model="btype")
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=scope_limit)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I'd like the JSON for the list method of the ToSerialize viewset to look like:

```
[
    {
       "atype": { "id": 1, "foo": "a" }
    },
    {
       "atype": { "id": 2, "foo": "b" }
    },
    {
       "btype": { "id": 1, "bar": "1" }
    },
    {
       "btype": { "id": 2, "bar": "2" }
    }
]
```

Is there a way I can have the serializer for the ToSerialize object's viewset produce "conditional fields" based on the content_type/object_id that will achieve this effect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [SerializeMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    your_conditional_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ToSerialize

    def get_your_conditional_field(self, obj):
        # do your conditional logic here
        # and return appropriate result
        return obj.content_type > obj.object_id
```

Comment: Will the conditional field be "removed" from the results if there is no value ?

Comment: @GhislainLeveque, `SerializeMethodField` is a read-only field meaning it only appears when serializing a model to JSON. You can't assign a value to it when deserializing from JSON to an instance.

Comment: @GhislainLeveque no it will still be included. I am not sure this answer addresses the question.

Comment: @th0th, the question is asking to INCLUDE the field based on some conditions.

Comment: @SamRad yes, and the your_conditional_field is included in the result even if it returns None?

Comment: @th0th, yes. Whatever returns from the function will be in the result. If you wanna remove it if it's None, then Google "DRF dynamic serialized fields".

Answer (score 20):

None of the answers actually answer the question.

The easy thing to do is to add all the fields by default and then remove it at initialisation of the serializer depending on your condition.

In the example below, we don't give back the emails when listing users.

```py
class UserSerializer():

    fields = ('username', 'email')

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Don't return emails when listing users
        if kwargs['context']['view'].action == 'list':
            del self.fields['email']

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This does not work with `QuerySet`s which are used in `ListAPIView`s.

Comment: @ErdinEray maybe try with a **ViewSet**. `ViewSets` and  `*View` are easy to mix but they have very different interfaces

Comment: Sorry, I could not edit my comment so I'd like to add something else. I wanted to access `instance` parameter on `__init__` because I wanted to conditionally remove some fields based on some attributes on model instance. In this context (accessing `instance`), it will not work in `ListAPIView`. Your example accesses `context` which is totally fine and will work in `ListAPIView`s.

Comment: @ErdinEray I'm a bit confused with what you mean. The example I have works well with a viewset (haven't tested with "api view"). So just make sure that your class view inherits a viewset instead of an "api view". It should work

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way is to create custom **RelatedField**. Check [DRF docs about generic relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships) for a nice example. In the OP case it would look like this:

```
class ABTypeRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        """
        Serialize objects to a simple textual representation.
        """
        if isinstance(value, AType):
            return 'AType: ' + value.foo
        elif isinstance(value, BType):
            return 'BType: ' + value.bar
        raise Exception('Unexpected type of content_object')


class ToSerializeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    content_object = ABTypeRelatedField()
```