# Django REST, serializing variable/multiple nested OnetoOne relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Apologies if the title is unclear as to what the issue is, I'm unsure how to describe it.

I have a "parent" survey model which holds my general fields which all surveys have in common.

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    ...
```

However depending on the type of survey, additional/different fields are required

```
class SurveyA(models.Model):
    survey = models.OneToOneField(
        Survey,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
    fieldA = models.TextField()

class SurveyB(models.Model):
    survey = models.OneToOneField(
        Survey,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
    fieldC = models.TextField()

class SurveyN(models.Model):
    survey = models.OneToOneField(
        Survey,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
    fieldN = models.TextField()
```

When I serialize a "Survey" object into json, I would like the corresponding SurveryA,B..N object to be serialized along with it, regardless of which type of sub survey is related back in the `OnetoOneField`. Is this doable?

Expected output when serializing all `Survey` models:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "SurveyA": {
            "fieldA": "this is an 'A' type Survey",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "SurveyB": {
            "fieldB": "this is an 'B' type Survey",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "SurveyN": {
            "fieldN": "this is an 'N' type Survey",
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using [SerializeMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), if anyone has any other suggestion it would be much appreciated.

Idea from [Django Rest Framework Conditional Field on Serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947868/django-rest-framework-conditional-field-on-serializer)

```
class SurveySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    survey_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_survey_type(self, obj):
        if SurveyA.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).exists():
            survey_type = SurveyASerializer(SurveyA.objects.get(pk=obj.pk), context=self.context)
        elif SurveyB.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).exists():
            survey_type = SurveyBSerializer(SurveyB.objects.get(pk=obj.pk), context=self.context)
        elif SurveyN.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).exists():
            survey_type = SurveyNSerializer(SurveyN.objects.get(pk=obj.pk), context=self.context)
        return survey_type.data
```

Note: `context=self.context` must be passed because I'm working with hyperlinked models.